# Pandas set_levels, how to avoid sorting of labels?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I came across a problem using `set_levels` of multi index

```
from io import StringIO

txt = '''Name,Height,Age
"",Metres,""
A,-1,25
B,95,-1'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt),header=[0,1],na_values=['-1',''])

df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.get_level_values(level=1).str.replace('Un.*',''),level=1)

     Name Height   Age
   Metres             
0      A    NaN  25.0
1      B   95.0   NaN
```

If I run the same command again

```
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.get_level_values(level=1).str.replace('Un.*',''),level=1)

  Name Height   Age
       Metres      
0    A    NaN  25.0
1    B   95.0   NaN
```

Now this is yielding the expected result. Why is this behaviour so? Is it possible to keep the labels unsorted at the first try itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not completely understand why this happens but I found what causes the problem and a solution:

If we look at the column labels we can see something weird

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt),header=[0,1],na_values=['-1',''])
>>> df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[['Age', 'Height', 'Name'], ['Metres', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1']],
           labels=[[2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2]])
```

The indices of the second level don't match the indices of the first layer. And when you replace the strings you do that on the array that is in the *correct* order:

```
>>> df.columns.get_level_values(level=1)
Index(['Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Metres', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1'], dtype='object')
```

But you can get the array that's in the *incorrect* order just by indexing:

```
>>> df.columns.levels[1]
Index(['Metres', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1'], dtype='object')
```

So to remove the Unnamed indices:

```
>>> df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.levels[1].str.replace('Un.*', ''), level=1)
>>> df

  Name Height   Age
       Metres
0    A    NaN  25.0
1    B   95.0   NaN
```

However I would love for someone to point out why using the `get_` and `set_levels` has this behavior.

Comment: I too am curious, now the problem is with `get_level_values` ?.

Comment: That works because of the way the labels are structured: `labels=[[2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2]]`. The first and second index of the second layer keep getting swapped around each time you call it. And to elaborate on your first remark: The problem is with the way the labels are structured *(I think)*.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need , This will modify base on your original structure

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x : '' if 'Unnamed' in x else x , level=1)
Out[106]: 
  Name Height   Age
       Metres      
0    A    NaN  25.0
1    B   95.0   NaN
```

Comment: that's a good alternative. But I want to know why it is being sorted.

Comment: @Dark when you are using get_level_values, you get the level, but you have the multiple index , which means label info is important as well