# How to deal with unnamed columns in multiindex dataframe after reading csv file?

Tags: pandas, csv, multi-index

My csv (multiindex columns) looks like this:

```
,,companyName
,,2014_counts
nationalClass,nationalClassTitle,
426,"Food or edible material: processes, compositions, and products",31
424,"Drug, bio-affecting and body treating compositions",25
```

I am trying to programmatically read csv files using this code:

```py
dfs=[]
csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
    
# read each csv file into a df
for file in csv_files:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', header=[0,1,2], index_col=0))
```

My output is:

| nationalClass | Unnamed: 1_level_0 Unnamed: 1_level_1 nationalclassTitle | companyName 2014_counts Unnamed: 2_level_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 426 | Food or edible material: processes, compositio... | 31 |
| 424 | Drug, bio-affecting and body treating composit... | 25 |

My **desired** output is:

| nationalClass | nationalclassTitle | companyName 2014_counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 426 | Food or edible material: processes, compositio... | 31 |
| 424 | Drug, bio-affecting and body treating composit... | 25 |

I do not want to create new MultiIndex and assign to columns as shown in this answer:
[Mark Empty values in Pandas DataFrame Multi-Row Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059994/mark-empty-values-in-pandas-dataframe-multi-row-header)

Comment: try using skiprows=3, header=None then change your column names after you read the file. also using append if you have a lot of files is slower than collecting each dataframe to a list then use pd.concat().

Comment: There are two problems here: 1. skiprows flattens my multiindex column, which I would like to maintain; 2.  I do not want to rename cols later because they are coming from a variable, so I do not want to lose them.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your output:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=",", header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=0)
print(df)
# Output

                          Unnamed: 1_level_0        companyName
                          Unnamed: 1_level_1        2014_counts
nationalClass             nationalClassTitle Unnamed: 2_level_2
426            Food or edible material: p...                 31
424            Drug, bio-affecting and bo...                 25
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [get_level_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```py
# Save "nationalClass" for later
name = df.columns.names[2]

# Rename values in first and second levels
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: "" if "Unnamed" in x else x, level=0)
df = df.rename(
    columns=lambda x: df.columns.get_level_values(2)[0] if "Unnamed" in x else x,
    level=1,
)

# Remove third level and add previously saved index name
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(2)
df.columns.names = ("", name)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

                                             companyName
nationalClass             nationalClassTitle 2014_counts
426            Food or edible material: p...          31
424            Drug, bio-affecting and bo...          25
```